# Ackermann Function of (4,2)

Tags: java, recursion

How efficient is this program? How could I make it more efficient?

```
package main;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Ackermann {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ack(BigInteger.valueOf(4),BigInteger.valueOf(2)));

    }

    public static BigInteger ack(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
        BigInteger ans;
        if (a.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) ans = b.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        else if (b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) ans = ack(a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE),BigInteger.valueOf(1));
        else ans = ack(a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), ack(a,b.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
        return (ans);
    }

}
```

Comment: As far as I remember, ack(4,2) is 2^65533-3. Since the only way that ack() can return a specific value is to recurse that deep, there is no way that a machine will ever execute that algorithm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Ackermann function is not designed to be efficient... ;-) It is designed to be a counter-proof to a theoretical construct.

But, the reality is that the `BigInteger` is required. The conditions are required.

About the only things I can suggest are:

- use better names
- return-early logic
- the `ans` variable is unnecessary
- always use braces for conditional blocks.
- `BigInteger.ONE` is already defined, you have used it in some places already, no need for `BigInteger.valueOf(1)`
- call it `ackermann` not `ack`

I would have:

```
public static BigInteger ackermann(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    if (a.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return b.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    if (b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return ackermann(a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE),BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    return ackermann(a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), ackermann(a, b.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```

Comment: This question made me wonder if memoization might help out at all, and apparently the answer is no: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13088510/2388145

Answer (score 0):

This guy Jon Hanna in the linked Stackeroverflow question uses a non-recursive but iterative strategy with some extra Ackermann specific optimizations.
It is in c# but I hope it gives you some interesting insights.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186672/how-can-i-prevent-my-ackerman-function-from-overflowing-the-stack/

He gets an answer for Ackerman(4,2) in a little over a second which I find impressive.
My implementation will take a couple of lifecycles of the universe to complete.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a review of the code in the question.

Comment: True. However it does provide some pointers in answering the question in the question: "How could I make it more efficient?"
Since I am new to this platform I am open to removing my answer if it is not in line with expectations and habits.